# Special character in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, special-characters

I using SQL Server and need to search

```
WHERE Lastname LIKE '$pName%' 

$pName = "Eugène%";
```

This returns an empty result, but when I try with `$pName = "Eug%";`, I get all the matching rows. The special character is not letting me search.

I tried

```
$pName = mb_convert_encoding($pName, 'UTF-8', 'ASCII');
```

but it still not letting me search.

How can I determine which set up this table in the database is ?

Comment: you can try  `LIKE N'$pName%'`

Comment: Select LastName from persons WHERE Lastname LIKE N'Eugène%'   :No rows found

Comment: What datatype is `Lastname`? What datatype is `$pName`?

Comment: nvarchar(50,null)

Comment: What's with the dollar sign in `$pName`?   Is this being done from some front end application?   Please tag accordingly.   If this is done entirely in SQL Server, please add a script that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Yes  Tab Alleman, $pName is parameter from front end application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solution was to convert to ISO format

```
$pName = mb_convert_encoding($pName, 'ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8');
```